# Error: cannot find GRLDR in all drives

Tags: boot

When I try to install ubuntu 14.04, I'm presented with the following error:

```
Try (hd0,0): FAT16: no GRLDR
Try (hd0,1): NTFS5: 3
Try (0,2): invalid or null
Try (hd0,3): invalid or null
Try (fd0): invalid or null
Error: cannot find GRLDR in all drive. CTRL+ALT+DEL to restart.
```

I have no idea what a GRLDR is. I cannot get past the boot menu.

What should I do?

Comment: Not related to standard install. Either you are installing wubi which is not supported or that is from EasyBCD which is Windows. They use the very old grub4dos. Ubuntu uses grub2. http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Where did you download Ubuntu from?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://neosmart.net/wiki/cannot-find-grldr/) method?